# Lombok @Builder not initializing collections

Tags: java, lombok

I am using Lombok's `@Data` and `@Builder` annotations like this:

```
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class Movie {

    // Some other fields here.

    private final List<Actor> actors;

}
```

When I create a new `Movie` using the builder, without specifying any actors, I would expect Lombok to initialize my List to `Collections.emptyList()`. But this does not happen:

```
List<Actor> actors = Movie.builder().build().getActors();
System.out.println(actors); // Prints 'null'.
```

In the documentation for the `@Builder` annotation, it is stated at line 55 and 56 in the code-example for Vanilla Java (https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html) that I should look at the code example for `@Singular` (https://projectlombok.org/features/Singular-snippet.html). At line 112 in the Vanilla Java example here, it seems like the list should be initialized to the empty list.

I checked, and it does indeed happen if I annotate the list with `@Singular`:

```
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class Movie {

    // Some other fields here.

    @Singular
    private final List<Actor> actors;

}

List<Actor> actors = Movie.builder().build().getActors();
System.out.println(actors); // Prints '[]'.
```

Is this a bug in Lombok, or is there something that I am doing wrong? According to the documentation, it seems like the list should be initialized to the empty list in both cases (because the `@Builder` doc refers to the `@Singular` doc).

Comment: I am using Lombok version 1.16.6 by the way.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Only when you use `@Singular`, you get an empty list. On the [Builder documentation page](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html#singular) it says:

> …with the `@Singular` annotation, lombok will treat that builder node as a collection.

Without the `@Singular`, lombok treats it as any other object. So it will be `null` instead of an empty Collection.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer

Comment: Thanks! By the way, the `@Singular` annotation gives an error if the variable name of the collection can't be singularized. However, this is a little inconvenient when you have an uncountable noun as a variable name (such as the word "equipment", or "sheep"). Why can't the generated singular method be named the same as the plural one, instead of giving a compile error?

Comment: Our short research let us to believe there are not many of those words used in actual software. Whenever lombok is unsure, we err on the safe side. Isn't it a warning?

Comment: I realized I can just specify the name like this `@Singular("equipment")`, and it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or you can use `@Builder.Default` annotation and initialise that filed yourself.

Comment: I tried to use @Singular but my list is still null and not an empty list...

Comment: Awesome feature. In fact I think it should become the default.

Comment: Even using `Builder.Default` e.g. on a list or set, you can do `myObj = myBuilder.myList(null).build()` and then `myObj.getMyList()` will return `null`. I'd love for there to be an option for lombok to initialize `myList` to an empty list if it was set to `null` via the builder.

Comment: @JeroenKransen but that would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 38):

Since Lombok v1.16.16, you can use @Builder‘s inner annotation to initialize your collection by default. For example:

```
@Data
@Builder
class Movie {

@Builder.Default
private final List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

So when you create a new Movie using the builder, without specifying any actors:

```
Movie movie = Movie.builder().build();
movie.getActors(); // Will return instance of ArrayList
```

Comment: This worked for me (w Lombok v. 1.18.12).  For me this was the better answer as this solves exactly the problem (same as OP) without needing the `@Singular` annotation, which changes other `@Builder` behaviour I did not want.

Comment: Without the `final` modifier, this removes the default for the constructor call and might result in NPE.